# Convert a Python snippet to PHP?

Tags: php, python, code-snippets

Can anyone translate my small Python snippet to PHP? I'm not a familiar with both languages. :(

```
matches = re.compile("\"cap\":\"(.*?)\"")
totalrewards = re.findall(matches, contents)
print totalrewards
```

Thank you for those who'd help! :(

Comment: `print totalrewards` prints a human-readable interpretation of the result - are you looking to do something else with the data? My answer does a similar human-readable dump, but it's not in exactly the same format - is that what you need?

Comment: yes i wanted it to list all the result :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct translation of the code above, with "contents" populated for demonstration purposes:

```
<?php
$contents = '"cap":"foo" "cap":"wahey"';
if (preg_match_all('/"cap":"(.*?)"/', $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

The output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) ""cap":"foo""
    [1]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) ""cap":"wahey""
    [1]=>
    string(5) "wahey"
  }
}
```

If you want to actually do something with the result, for e.g. list it, try:

```
<?php
$contents = '"cap":"foo" "cap":"wahey"';
if (preg_match_all('/"cap":"(.*?)"/', $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        // array index 1 corresponds to the first set of brackets (.*?)
        // we also add a newline to the end of the item we output as this
        // happens automatically in PHP, but not in python.
        echo $match[1] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way the Python variable `totalrewards` is equivalent to `$matches[0][1]` if you use the code above.

Comment: When I run the python code above for a contents of '"cap":"foo" "cap":"wahey"', I get ['foo', 'wahey'] as the output. I posted a comment on the question about the nature of required output, but considering "print totalrewards" essentially prints a human-readable dump of a data structure, I consider "var_dump($matches)" to be functionally equivalent in a pure Python to PHP translation.

Comment: um how will I be able to make it list the "foo" and "wahey" like:

foo
wahey
etc
etc

i tried looking up var_dump() but apparently my mind can't comprehend how to use it or how it works xD
sorry if i'm being somewhat dumb

Comment: Updated again to give you the output you wanted.